# dmcloud (daily motion) CloudKey_RPCException being thrown on prod environment on upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

The error below only occurs when I upload my code to the server. When I'm on my local development environment works perfectly. My local is Windows and my Production is Linux.

What does this mean? What should I do to solve it?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CloudKey_RPCException' with message 'You must provide an url for mp4_h264_aac' in /var/www/application/libraries/CloudKey.php:336 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/application/libraries/VideoUploader.php(56): CloudKey_Api->__call('create', Array) #1 /var/www/application/libraries/VideoUploader.php(56): CloudKey_Media->create(Array) #2 /var/www/application/controllers/Admin.php(519): VideoUploader->upload(Array, Array, '06d88cc1721cbe1...') #3 [internal function]: Admin->videos('upload') #4 /var/www/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(356): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /var/www/public/index.php(274): require_once('/var/www/system...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/application/libraries/CloudKey.php on line 336

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case anyone ever needs this. The problem is that, I was using the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] directly into DMCloud method. Turns out that on Windows, it's something like C:\temp\file.tmp and on linux is something like /tmp/file. DMCloud api requires that the file used for upload must have an extension.

So, it failed to upload the file, and when I tried to use the URL of the failed upload, it gaveme this exception.

I hope someone fin this hopeful in the future =)